# Insertion sort running time

Tags: sorting, computer-science, insertion-sort

Which of the following statements about insertion and selection sort is correct?

```
a) insertion-sort runs in omega(n^2)
b) the insert operation (for one element) in selection sort takes omega(n^2) time.
c) insertion-sort runs in O(n) time
d) the removeMin operation in selection-sort takes omega(n) time.
```

(Not a homework question, just doing things for final practice).

- As for A, wouldn't the omega be `O(N)`? (looking at old questions on the website)
- For B, wouldn't inserting take `O(N)`? Comparing 1 element vs. a whole array and if O(n) then omega can't be `n^2`.
- For C, Insertion Sort's worse case is `O(n^2)`...
- For D, wouldn't the best case of removing the Min be `O(1)`?

All of these seem wrong to me.

Edit: To anyone who says this is a homework question or something in that sense, please read the question before even assuming that. I'm wondering which one is right because they all seem wrong. Yes, I have a textbook. Yes, I can read Wikipedia.Yes, I have notes. However, if I came here it is not because I want an easy answer, rather to know why my reasoning is wrong. So, if you're not bothered to look at the entirety of the question, don't answer at all.

Comment: a) - correct - O(n^2),  b) - incorrect, O(n), c - incorrect, O(n^2), d) - correct, O(n).